# Waiting after setPadding() in Android

Tags: android

I have the following problem: I have an image in my App and the position shall change dynamically. The following code works already:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
image.setPadding(startX, startY, 0, 0);
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    startX+=10;
    image.setPadding(startX, startY, 0, 0);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the image position is immediately changed to the final position, so I added the Thread.sleep lines. However, now the thread sleeps for 10x 3s and then the image changes to the final position. I also tried doing it in a new thread which didn't work as well.

Any thoughts on how I could reach my goal? I am happy for any solutions or input.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/ for formatting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `Handler` and `Runnable` to achieve this behaviour :

Step 1 : define your Handler and Runnable

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable refreshRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      refreshView();
                    }
                }
```

Step 2 : Here's your refreshView function :

```
private void refreshView() {
  count ++;  //Variable initialized at 0 in your class
  if (count < 10) {
    startX += 10;
    dotGreen.setPadding(startX, startY, 0, 0);
    dotGreen.invalidate();
    handler.postDelayed(refreshRunnable, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I get "cannot find symbol variable runnable in the line "    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);"